# Passing a const reference vector to another function that takes const reference vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to pass a vector that was initially passed to a function as `const vector&`, to another function that take `const vector&`, but I am getting the error:

```
In constructor ‘Bus::Bus(const std::vector<unsigned char>&)’:
no matching function for call to ‘Dram::Dram()’
    5 | Bus::Bus (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary)
```

This is the code:

```
// Create a new instance of Bus.
Bus::Bus (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary)
{
    dram = Dram (binary);
}

...

Dram::Dram (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Random guess: You should be using a member initializer list (e.g.: `Bus::Bus (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary) : dram(binary) {}`

Comment: Do you have this `Dram::Dram` constructor forward declared somewhere prior to using it?

Comment: Because there is no [mre] in this question, we must make guesses about code that we can not see here.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to default initialize the `dram` member variable, and then assign a new vector initialized `Dram` object to it afterwards. But `Dram` doesn't have a default constructor, which is what the error message is complaining about.

Instead, use the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) in `Bus()`:

```cpp
Bus::Bus (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary) 
    : // colon starts the member initializer list
    dram(binary) // use the Dram constructor taking the vector
{
    // empty constructor body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message

```
In constructor ‘Bus::Bus(const std::vector<unsigned char>&)’:
no matching function for call to ‘Dram::Dram()’
    5 | Bus::Bus (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary)
```

means that to create the object with the name  `dram` used within the body of the constructor `Bus`  the default constructor of the class `Dram` is required that is absent.

To avoid the problem you could write using the mem-initializer list

```
Bus::Bus (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary) : dram( binary )
{
}
```

In this case the constructor

```
Dram::Dram (const std::vector<uint8_t>& binary)
{
    ...
}
```

will be used to create the data member `dram` of the class `Bus`.